# How to insert a new element at the beginning of std::vector without any copy and default constructing overhead if I know the number of elements?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std

I need to fill from end some preallocated uninitialized memory region. I want to use std::vector, but I don't want inserting each new element at the beginning of vector forcing it to make unnecessary copies and another overhead. Is there any way to achieve this with std::vector?

Comment: What type do the vector elements have?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet? From where do you know, what the "end" is? And when you know what the end is, why do you don't know the beginning?

Comment: Is there a reason to not store the "reverse order" and therefore use `push_back`? Otherwise maybe a different container is a better option `deque` or `list` or such. With vector I can only think of hacky solutions using like `optional`/placement-new to avoid `resize` calling all constructors.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I don't know beginning, because constructing of first elements depends on computations which is performed in constructors of previous elements. All these elements is restored from a file. And this is important to save that order without overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting an element at the beginning of a non empty `std::vector` always implies copying plus allocation overhead if the new `size` of the vector will be greater then the `capacity` of the vector. This is by design, since a `std::vector` has its uninitialized memory at the end of it or to quote THE C++ standard:

> 26.3.11.1 Class template vector overview [vector.overview] 1 A vector is a sequence container that supports (amortized) constant time insert
>   and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take
>   linear time.

Knowing the number of elements is irrelevant in this regard, as long as you want to stick to `std::vector`. You can use it to minimize the allocation overhead by using `reserve()` i.e. increasing the capacity before hand, but as long as you are inserting not at the end of the vector, you will have copying overhead.

Consider using a `std::deque` if you don't know the total number of elements, otherwise use an `std::array`.

Comment: I dont understand what the question asks for but it says "but I don't want inserting each new element at the beginning of vector", so inserting in the beginning seems not what OP is asking for...

Comment: title says something different though

Comment: Both body and title says it: "new element at the beginning of vector" @idclev463035818

Comment: It's rather I want behavior which is similar to behavior of dynamic array where I can preallocate memory of known size and fill it randomly, but in this case from the end, because first elements depends on computations which is performed in constructors of previous elements. All these elements is restored from a file. And this is important to save that order without overhead. Sorry, I'm repeating myself.

Comment: I still dont understand 100%: Why dont just store them in the order from the file into the container, add the computed elements,and read it in a reverse order later?

Comment: And how about `std::array`? Why does it has to be a `std::vector`? You are giving no code and have conflicting/confusing requirements, most likely a XY problem.

Comment: As far as I know std::array is statically-sized, but the number of elements will grow after restoring from file.

Comment: When the elements are created in first place they are pushed back into the vector. Then each new element changes some data in all previous elements (to be specific — location in space). When I reconstruct them from file, firstly, I have to compute location and dimensions of last one. To do so I have to initialize it in place in order to avoid any overhead.

Comment: And I can't save location and dimension to the file, because this file can be opened in another environment. Of course I can initialize each element with default location and then recompute. But still, this is overhead. And I want to understand how I can do that without any.

Comment: I am sorry but your text is confusing and contradictory, [please add compiling code to your question on how you want to use the container](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use `rbegin` and `rend` instead of `begin` and `end`, then `push_back` adds elements to the "beginning" of the reversed view.